# Как получить список степеней двойки разложения числа на сумму степеней двоек?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру: число `13` (`0b1101`), как мне получить список степеней двоек, присутствующих в его разложении на сумму степеней двоек? Т.е. для числа `13` мне необходимо получить список `[0, 2, 3]` (`13 == 2**0 + 2**2 + 2**3`) (порядок неважен).

---

Моя попытка сделать это:

```py
def foo(n):
    return [index for index, bit in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if bit == "1"]


print(foo(13))
```

---

На самом деле, ответил сам себе, пока писал вопрос, но теперь интересует более рациональное (более *Pythonic* решение этой задачи) без использования сторонних модулей.

Comment: если foo(n) переименовать в setbit_indices(n), то уже решение читаемое/простое и краткое. Если решение хотите по другим параметрам оценивать или просто посмотреть хотите какие варианты есть, то укажите в вопросе¶ Можно [] на {} заменить, чтобы set вернуть.

Comment: А что подразумевается под рациональностью? Например, по-моему более рационально использовать побитовые операции (& и >>), а не перегонять число в строку  и т.п. Но для Python вряд ли эффективность играет роль

Comment: Вообще-то, именно это решение, на мой взгляд, наиболее питонистое. Кроме того, как здесь (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201447/express-a-number-as-a-sum-of-powers-of-2 ) сказано, оно чуть ли не самое эффективное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вообще-то, именно это решение, на мой взгляд, наиболее питонистое. Кроме того, как здесь (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201447/express-a-number-as-a-sum-of-powers-of-2) сказано, оно чуть ли не самое эффективное. © [strawdog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/311069)

---

> более рационально использовать побитовые операции (& и >>), а не перегонять число в строку и т.п. © [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659)

Такой вариант был опробован и выяснилось, что работа со строкой быстрее. См. [Почему работа со строкой быстрее побитовых операций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/964976/324059).