# Почему работа со строкой быстрее побитовых операций?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Передо мной стояла задача: [Как получить список степеней двойки разложения числа на сумму степеней двоек?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964698/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA)
Её я реализовал следующим образом:

```py
[index for index, bit in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if bit == "1"]
```

Но в комментариях мне дали ссылку на подобный вопрос на англоязычном SO, где был вариант (который, на мой взгляд, должен быть быстрее моего) с побитовыми операциями, и вариант решения с ними выглядел так:

```py
[index for index in range(n.bit_length()) if n & (1 << index)]
```

Увидев его я без раздумий заменил своё решение на это. Но потом выяснилось, что моё решение работает быстрее, хотя, казалось бы, побитовые операции должны работать ощутимо быстрее, чем работа со строкой. Теперь возник вопрос: **почему работа со строкой оказалась быстрее побитовых операций?**

---

Время замерял следующим образом:

```py
import time


N = 2**22


def bitwise(n : int) -> list:
    return [index for index in range(n.bit_length()) if n & (1 << index)]


def string(n : int) -> list:
    return [index for index, bit in enumerate(bin(n)[:1:-1]) if bit == "1"]


start = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    bitwise(i)
print(time.time() - start)


start = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    string(i)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Вывод:

> 57.37398672103882
>   40.31372857093811

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201447/express-a-number-as-a-sum-of-powers-of-2 - это та самая ссылка, мало ли, кому-то интересно будет

Comment: Так и не выяснилось почему быстрее? :)

Comment: @gil9red Не выяснилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже тормоза в загрузке `n` в итератор. В варианте со строкой все операции решаются на стеке. В варианте `bitwise` есть опкод `LOAD_DEREF 0 (n)`. Это означает, что `n` не локальна и операции с ней будут чуть медленнее.

Но это ещё не всё. Подгрузка `n` в вариант со строкой сделала функцию медленнее, но она все ещё бысрее битовой.